# How can i improve my information architecture skills?

Tags: information-architecture

How can i improve my information architecture skills ? I believe in improving skills by practice. To give you an example, how about creating an application similar to any of the common application. Gather all the possibile features by comparitative analysis and then create an IA based on that. And continue practicing the same way.

Comment: Wow, looks like you posted an answer as a question. you think you can rephrase it? =)

Comment: It's probably only my opinion, but I don't think that fictional training helps. Being an information architect / interaction designer / UX specialist or what ever requires real data feedback, whether qualitative or quantitative, but still *real*. When you just analize and recreate but don't get feedback, there's nothig real to gain from. However, might be only my opinion.

Comment: This isn't really the best place to ask such questions, i'm afraid. As per the [faq] "We prefer questions that elicit definitive answers or solutions rather than prolonged discussions. Remember, this a Q&A site, not a discussion board."

Comment: There's a surprise!

Answer (score 3):

Reading this book <del>would be a good start</del> **is essential** for anyone involved in UX or IA: **[Information Architecture for the World Wide Web](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596527349)**

Comment: I can recommend this book also.